# Why Referencing DOM nodes in Angular expressions is disallowed?

Tags: angularjs

According to [angularJs documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/%24parse/isecdom):

Referencing DOM element in angular expression is an error. Why is it so? What is that angularjs is trying to prevent by making such practise as error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally from the page you linked:

> AngularJS restricts access to DOM nodes from within expressions since it's a known way to execute arbitrary Javascript code.

In understandable English, now - It's a security thing. To protect malicious users/dependencie developers from running malicious code that could harm the application or it's users.

You can read up on what is Code Injection - then thing angular is protecting you from here, over on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) and on Javascript code injection over on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134024/HTML-and-JavaScript-Injection).